# how to increment counter number in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have person details like for one person first name,last name and age, then second person first name,last name and age. In XSLT I need output a file like:

```
<personData>
    <personNo>1</personNo>
    <firstname>fff</firstname>
</personData>
<personData>
    <personNo>2</personNo>
    <firstname>dd</firstname>
    <lastname>fcv</lastname>
</personData>
```

So please, can any one suggest me how to increment the value of `personNo` in the loop?

I don't know how to increment  1 2 3 ... for each iteration..

Comment: Where is your input XML and XSLT code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: XSLT is a functional language and you can't think in terms of "iterations" and "incrementing". Show us the input xml and we can advise on alternative approaches to the problem. Also, what version of XSLT are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to increment a counter. Use either one of the following:

1. the position() function;
2. the `<xsl:number>` element;
3. count of the preceding siblings + 1